# Olap database processing options and objects

Tags: ssis, ssas, olap, olap-cube, ssas-2008

Could you please help me with understanding olap processing options and which of olap databse object need to be processed in different cases?

1. When we need to process full and entire olap databse?
2. When we need to process and in which type just cube?
3. When we need to process and in which type just a new element that had been added (new or restructered dimension, measure)?

And what about SSIS in this way? Is it a good way to use ssis package for process cube elements?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 Process full is required when you have done structural change ie attribute added or deleted.

2) Go throw link 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/karang/2011/01/25/different-kinds-of-ssas-processing-in-simple-words/

3 For any structural change you have to Process full (new or restructured dimension, measure are structural changes).

SSIS is one of the good option for processing cube dynamically .

Comment: For example - I have olap databse with cube partitions by day. After insert information with bew day to dimensions and fact table we create new partition for last date. Is it right to process full just all dimensions that had been altered after insert and new partition with last date? There is no reason to process full database or cube, cause we added new information just for one day? Thanks.

Comment: Process Add or  Process Update (if data can change in dimension) for dimension  and Process Add or process partition https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa216703%28SQL.80%29.aspx     All task could be performed SSIS usinf XMLA

Comment: I guess if I have small dimensions there is no difference in time between process full and process add/update. So is it a good choice to process just new info after update fact table and dimensions? All my last projects were not so big and I had always processed full database after insert one new day.